# How to switch img tag src to data-src with grunt tasks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I search a lot for this but couldn't find any leads. 
I am working on a web based HTML5 magazine project. I am getting the magazine with layout from Indesign export of our designer. The layout and everything works as expected. But because of the heavy load of the images inside html, i want to load them programmaticly such as lazy load. But to do this i have to switch img src tags with data-src tags. I am wondering if i can make this work with grunt tasks. I have to do this every month and i am already using grunt in this job.

Comment: http://gruntjs.com/plugins is full of css image to base64 tasks, but I haven't found one to do what you want :(

Comment: Yes. I found them too. It shouldn't be that hard probably but i am missing something. I am new to grunt and its task structure. I am sure there is a proper way to do this somewhere.